# Unable to cut and paste between 2D & 3D layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I have two point layers, one with a subset of the fields of the other.  I want to cut and paste points from the layer with fewer fields into the other but QGIS will not allow me.

Source layer is created in memory by a python script and has a 2D geometry.
Destination layer is a postgres table with 3D geometry.

I get a banner message across the top of the window saying No points copies and the message vanishes before I can study it in detail.  There are some symbols that might be buttons but I can't tell.

The issue is that I can't figure out what is wrong as there are no error messages that I can find in the logs.

How can I diagnose the issue?

QGIS 2.18.7 on a Mac.

Comment: Different geometries is your answer I guess

Comment: Another guess is that the Postgis table lacks a primary key.

Comment: It was geometries. After a considerable voyage of discovery I managed to get my script to produce transformed 3D geometries that I was able to cut and paste.    I was pretty sure it was a QGIS issue rather than PostGIS because (in my limited experience) PostGIS issues don't happen until you save the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the python error logs on the bottom status bar

[image]

Select the Python tab and see what the error was.

Comment: I did that but did not recognise the error messages as relating to the problem!  The errors referred to 'spatialite' which is the provider for memory layers but I did not make the connection.